# IAP with Urban Airship

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com, in-app-purchase

I'm building a book store using Urban Airship In-App Purchase. I've already developed the reader, now I need to develop the store for in-app purchase.

In Urban Airship StoreFront, the store is only a list of products without categories and subcategories. It looks like that :
 - Product 1
 - Product 2
 - Product 3
 - ...
 - Product 199
 - Product 200

I want to create a bookstore with hundreds products. So I need to create categories and subcategories for my products. The store hierarchy I want to create is something like this :
 - Category 1
     -> Subcategory 1 (with products 1,2...10)
     -> Subcategory 2 (with products 11,12...20)
     -> Subcategory 3 (with products 21,22...30)
 - Category 2
     -> Subcategory 4 (with products 31,32...40)
     -> ...
 - Category 3
     -> ...
     -> Subcategory 20 (with products 191,192...200)

My question : How to get this hierarchy? How to modify IAPSample-latest.zip example to achieve this?

I guess I need to modify the loadInventory result from the UAStoreFront.m file, but I don't know how to start...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey did you achieved this ? And were you able to list down all the free as well as paid content in the USStore ?